# Export SharePoint Blog Posts to SharePoint Online Pages OR Word/PDF

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2016, export

SharePoint 2016 offered the blog site template to share knowledge and other stuff. When migrating to SharePoint Online this content can be a problem - **how to export the content and transfer it to SharePoint Online Modern Pages or to PDF/Word documents?**

Sure, you could do it by hand and waste dozens of hours. But it would be nice to have a path by automatically exporting and kind of importing the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SharePoint Modernization Framework from the PnP team, although going from a classic page to a modern page means there is no possible way it is going to be perfect, so you are still going to have to go page by page and clean things up after the modernization tool is run.

Tool: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-modernization/tree/master/Tools/SharePoint.Modernization/SharePointPnP.Modernization.Framework

Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-userinterface-site-pages

Comment: This looks really great! Did not know this. Something like this was what I was looking for! Thank you!